# Forking in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, fork, workflow

I am a newbie in Git workflow. In our company we are using Bitbucket and here is the workflow we adopted.

1- clone the master repository locally.

2- create a feature branch off the local master branch and carry out your changes.

3- commit your changes to the local feature branch.

4- pull the latest changes from the remote master to the local mater.

5- merge the local master branch to the local feature branch. Since usually our local feature branches are research project it took a while before they would be resolved. As such, this step is necessary to avoid merge conflict when creating pull-request.

6- push the local feature branch to the remote feature branch. In fact this is the first time the remote feature branch is created.

7- create a pull request so the manager can merge the remote feature branch into the remote master branch.

As you see, in this workflow we are not forking the remote master branch. In another word the pushed featured branch is the fork master branch incorporating our changes. However that remote feature branch is created at very last stage of the work while the fork master branch should be create at the very beginning.

Does this workflow look correct or I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to have nothing to do with using a Bitbucket fork, because it lists steps that *avoid* using a Bitbucket fork.  If your question is *is this possible*, the answer is yes, of course it is possible; that is what your company is doing.  If your question is whether this is *wise*, a *good idea*, *good practice*, etc., such questions are off-topic on StackOverflow.com; consider using, e.g., softwareengineering.stackoverflow.com instead (but of course, check for existing questions first).

Comment: To be specific I want to know if forking remote master in absolutely necessary? Or as it is done within my company we can avoid having it ?

Comment: Of course it's not *necessary;* if it were, your company's procedure wouldn't work, but it does work.